# Transferring/Sharing Images using USB Programmatically

Tags: android, usb

I am using below ***code to print/share image via Bluetooth*** using Intent, but now I have to do same thing **(Transferring/sharing) image via USB** *programmatically*.

see my existing code, which I am using to transfer/share image using Bluetooth, but don't know how can I do same thing using USB

```
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(
                    "com.android.bluetooth",
                    "com.android.bluetooth.opp.BluetoothOppLauncherActivity"));
                intent.setType("image/jpeg");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(fileToPrint));
                startActivity(intent);
```